# Volley libray posting data twice

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am sending a post request to a PHP API using volley library on an android application. The problem am having is that it posts data twice.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    
                                    String responseMessage = jsonObject.getString("message");
                                    if(!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                                        DB.updateTransaction(msgCode,"sent");
                                        Toast.makeText(context, responseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                                    }


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        setConfigurationsReceiver(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent Received: "+intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction()==SMS_RECEIVED){
            Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(dataBundle != null){
                //creating PDU protocol Data unit object which is a protocol for transferring message
                Object[] mypdu = (Object[])dataBundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[mypdu.length];

                for(int i =0; i< mypdu.length; i++){
                    //for build version >= API
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                        String format = dataBundle.getString("format");
                        //From PDU we get all object and smsMessage using following line of code
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mypdu[i],format);
                    }else{
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) mypdu[i]);
                    }
                    msg += message[i].getMessageBody().toString().replace("null","");
                    phoneNo = message[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
                msg = msg.replace("null","");

                if(phoneNo.trim().equals("MPESA")) {
                    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
                    String[] msgArr = msg.split(" ");

                    String pat = "Ksh([0-9,.]+)";
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat,Pattern.MULTILINE);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);
                    if(matcher.find()){
                        amount = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1).replace(",",""));
                    }

                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    msgDate = dateFormat.format(date);
                    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    msgTime = timeFormat.format(date);

                    String msgCode = msgArr[0].trim();
                    dbHelper.insertTransaction(msgCode,amount,"",msgDate,msgTime,msg,clientId,tillNumber);
                    //insert to web
                    volleHelper = new VolleHelper(context);
                    volleHelper.mpesaApi(msgCode,amount,"",msgDate,msgTime,msg,clientId,tillNumber);
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "message: " + msg + "phone: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

    }
```

The posting is done in a method called mpesaApi in the volleHelper class. I call the method immediately an sms is received.
It does not post twice each time. The issue occurs when there is slow internet.

Comment: Could you post the code where you do this call? Like a button click or something? And not only the `onResponse` the full code

Comment: I call it when a message is received. I am using broadcast receiver to listen for incoming sms. So it posts data extracted from the message.

Comment: It only posts twice sometimes when the network is slow.

Comment: Could you post your Broadcastreceiver?

Comment: Edited the code

Comment: So when the connection is slow you see this twice in logcat? 
 Log.i(TAG, "Intent Received: "+intent.getAction());

Comment: It only appears once.

Comment: And this Toast?                     Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "message: " + msg + "phone: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Found out that i had registered the receiver twice. So the process ran twice.